# Difference between density and probability

Tags: r, probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

What is the difference between the density and probability?

I have tried R in which I can use both `pnorm` and `dnorm` for the normal distribution and `pbinom` and `dbinom` for the binomial distribution, etc.

I have tried reading the documentation but I don't think it's quite clear what the difference is between those two functions. I know that `pnorm(x)` gives me $P(X \leq x)$.

My guess is that the density is the value of $f(x)$ while the probability is $\int_\infty^x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. If this is correct, I don't understand what the value of $f(x)$ gives me of information since only the area under the function gives me the probability.

I know that the interesting values are pdf=probability density function and cdf=cumulative density function. So maybe the pdf is the value from `dnorm` and is the area at a specific x while cdf is the value from `pnorm` and is the area from $\infty$ to the specific x. But I have learned that you cannot get the probability at a specific $x$ in continuous distributions so that explanation does not make sense.

Comment: Additionally, interpretation of density is discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-is-a-density-function) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86487/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-density-of-a-distribution-at-a-point).

Answer (score 16):

[?dnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) is the density function for the normal distribution.  If you enter a quantile (i.e., a value for X), and the mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution in question, it will output the probability density.

[?pnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) is the distribution function for the normal distribution.  If you enter a quantile, and the mean and standard deviation of the normal distirubiton in question, it will output the probability of drawing a random variate from that distribution less than that quantile (you also have the option to specify greater than instead).

*(I'll add more in a bit.)*

You can also use these functions to plot the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the specified distribution.

[image]

Comment: At this point I think it's fair to say that "a bit" of time has past. I'm curious to know what more I had intended to add here...

Comment: Good post. pnorm is the cumulative distribution function, right? There's this "probability distribution function" term floating around too.

Comment: @TheThunderChimp, `pnorm()` is the CDF. 'Probability distribution function' is a nonstandard term; you'd have to ask whoever is using it exactly what they meant. 'Distribution function' is a common synonym for the CDF, so they may mean the CDF. What is potentially confusing is that 'probability distribution function' has the same initials as the 'probability *density* function' (PDF), which is a different thing from the CDF (it is the derivative).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you said was all correct.

`dnorm` is density function and `pnorm` is distribution function. Thus, `pnorm` is $F(x) = P(X <= x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)$ and `dnorm` is $f(x)$.

Since $f(x) = \frac{dF(x)}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{F(x+ \Delta x) - F(x)}{\Delta x}$, the value of $f(x)$ shows the probability that a random variable falls in the small interval. (You could treat $f(x)$ as constant in a small interval.)

Comment: This strikes me as mostly reasonable, but I think it is problematic to call the density "the probability that random variable falls in the small interval". Note that the density can exceed $1$ (see the thread linked under the question).

Comment: @gung is naturally correct. Any blurring of the dimensional difference between probability and probability density makes the distinction harder to grasp. Further, you say `dnorm` is ... and `pnorm` is ... but those are R functions for the normal (Gaussian) distribution, and your notation is more general for continuous distributions. Answers here should try not to be software-specific unless the question demands it.

Comment: @gung you are right. Density is not equal to probability. If treat density as constant in small interval, I should multiply the length of interval. Maybe the word "reflect" is better "show".

Answer (score 0):

Everything you write is correct. As far as I understand your question you are asking, you understand why pnorm(0) = 0.5, but you ask what

```
> pnorm(0)
[1] 0.5

> dnorm(0)
[1] 0.3989423
```

does the value `dnorm(0)` = 0.3989423, i.e. the height of the function mean, if it cannot be a probability? Since I cannot say it better, I refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23401