# Confusion about Maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

How can I see that the maximum likelihood approach finds the parameter values of the probability distribution that maximize the **probability** of the observed sample?
Maximum likelihood is not the maximum of **probability** in general because for, say, two continuous random variables $X_1, X_2$ we have $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "likelihood" and "probability"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability)

Comment: Or perhaps this: [Difference between density and probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156883/difference-between-density-and-probability)

Comment: Thank you! But what is that theoretical link that makes maximum likelihood maximum probability? This likelihood function appears as axiom, but I guess it should come from some other argument that makes it maximum probability.